# Plugin for tfs 2018 with ISubscriber - Events are not received

Tags: plugins, tfs, tfs-sdk

We developed a plugin for TFS that uses ISubscriber for handling the following events

- BuildCompletedEvent
- BuildStartedEvent

The plugin deployed at \Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins\
The plugin works excellent in TFS 2015 and TFS 2017.

Lastly, we wanted to add support for TFS 2018 and found that events are not received while the class that implements ISubscriber is initialized.

Event BuildStartedEvent is decorated as Deprecated in TFS 2018, but BuildCompletedEvent is not.

We need help to understand how to receive build start and build completed events in TFS 2018.